2N7000 pull-up resistor value
I'm level shifting a 5 V signal to an ESP32's input GPIO.
I'm using a 2N7000 MOSFET in that way:

The input signal has this shape:

The LOW pulse lasts 40 μs.
I've calculated a pull-up resistance of 220 kΩ. I've tested it on a breadboard and it works, but does this high resistance make sense?
Am I going to run into any side effects? (Maybe related to temperature, noises...)
Take in mind that this circuit is going to be mounted inside a house's fuse box.

"I've calculated a pull-up resistance of 220kOhm" Based on what?

To be honest it was chat gpt that did the magic.
It calculated the R value based on the capacitance of the gate (that is around C_gate=30 pF).
Since the t_fall = 40[us], then Tau=t_fall/5 = 8[us].
So the R_pullup = Tau/C_gate --> 8[us]/30[pF] = 267 kOhm. That's why I placed a 220kOhm.
I don't feel this is the way to calculate it: that's why I'm asking about it.

You need to ask yourself if the steep rise/fall time is the slightest relevant to your application. ChatGPT is a chat bot which is happy to make up anything based on some bogus assumption it read between the lines - it can't be used for engineering. If you are just toggling some supply with a MOSFET then all of this is utter nonsense and you should be using a much smaller pull-up. 10k is the standard value.

And in case the timing spec down to 40us does actually matter, then a MOSFET is likely the wrong component to begin with. Fast BJT or analog switches would be the correct choice.

Why not use a lower value pull up.

Please don't say you calculated it if you let ChatGPT give you a random value. Also the C_gate has nothing to do with the pull-up calculations. For future reference, it is far better to simply ask how to figure out a value for a pull-up, rather than circle around some erroneus values and methods what ChatGPT  provided to you, and for copyright reasons of the content not being produced by you but the ChatGPT algorithm.

ChatGPT is a notorious and unabashed liar. I’ve caught it fabricating entire citations- they finesse it as “hallucinations”.
Anyway, I suggest you simulate it in LTspice with some reasonable load capacitance and see how the output waveforms conform to your requirements. I suspect it might be okay with a 10k ohm pull-up, but not 220k. There is other capacitance than just the gate-source- drain-source and the drain-gate capacitance which affects the input via the Miller effect. Also use a reasonable source impedance for your driver, maybe 100 ohms.

The 220k pull-up is quite a high value.
It means that it will make the signal edge rise slowly. And depending on how you detect edges with the ESP, like with interrupts, slowly transitioning signals that linger a long time right at the threshold of logic low and high levels are very bad, as they are often interpreted as multiple input transitions which cause multiple interrupts even if you only have one slow transition.
Any noise getting coupled to the node with only weak 220k impedance will only make things worse.
The pull-up is rather useless, and could be left out, as even the internal pull-up of ESP32 IO pins is stronger, around 45 kohm.
The gate is driven by some external signal so gate capacitance does not have a direct RC effect with the pull-up on the drain. The drain and ESP32 input capacitances however will.
